# AS400 RUNSQL to printer output

Tags: ibm-midrange, cl, rpg

AS400 CL question:

Is it possible to use RUNSQL statement in batch CL program to generate a spool file for printing, like we can do with STRSQL + Shift F1 (Modify attributes)?

trying RUNSQL. I don't see any options to redirect output.

Comment: In fact, it's F13, not Shift-F1. 5250 has no concept of modifier keys being used with Function keys. That's a whole client-side thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In fact [RUNSQL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=environments-using-runsql-cl-command) doesn't even support the `SELECT` statement

> The following statements can be used by RUNSQL:
>
> - ALTER FUNCTION
> - ALTER MASK
> - ALTER PERMISSION
> - ALTER PROCEDURE
> - ALTER SEQUENCE
> - ALTER TABLE
> - ALTER TRIGGER
> - CALL
> - COMMENT
> - COMMIT
> - compound (dynamic)
> - CREATE ALIAS
> - CREATE FUNCTION
> - CREATE INDEX
> - CREATE MASK
> - CREATE PERMISSION
> - CREATE PROCEDURE
> - CREATE SCHEMA
> - CREATE SEQUENCE
> - CREATE TABLE
> - CREATE TRIGGER
> - CREATE TYPE
> - CREATE VARIABLE
> - CREATE VIEW
> - DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
> - DELETE
> - DROP
> - GRANT
> - INSERT
> - LABEL
> - MERGE
> - REFRESH TABLE
> - RELEASE SAVEPOINT
> - RENAME
> - REVOKE
> - ROLLBACK
> - SAVEPOINT
> - SET CURRENT DECFLOAT ROUNDING MODE
> - SET CURRENT DEGREE
> - SET CURRENT IMPLICIT XMLPARSE OPTION
> - SET CURRENT TEMPORAL SYSTEM_TIME
> - SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD
> - SET PATH
> - SET SCHEMA
> - SET TRANSACTION
> - TRANSFER OWNERSHIP
> - TRUNCATE
> - UPDATE

RUNSQL is designed to support DBA/DBE tasks, not reporting.

If you have the interactive SQL facility available, via STRSQL, then you also have the [Query Manager tooling](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v6r1/en_US/sc415212.pdf).  Use the `STRQM` command to get into the interactive version to define queries and their output forms.  The prompted mode looks a lot like Query/400, aka `WRKQRY`.  But QM is SQL based and you can create queries in non-prompted mode by entering an SQL statement.

Once you've created a QM query, you can use the `STRQMQRY` command to run it from the command line or a CL program.  Works fine for quick and dirty reports.

Of course IBM, would prefer you get with the times use Web Query.  It is a much nicer product and does support batch reporting.  But I believe it's still extra cost and isn't what I would call a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You can create a table with runsql
runsql sql('create table qtemp.x as (select * from table) with data')
then use
runqry qryfile((qtemp/x)) outtype(*Printer)